# How to receive short audio clips over bluetooth from an external device and play it from an iPhone?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming, avaudiosession

Is it possible to receive short audio clips from an external device over Bluetooth and then play it from the iPhone?

I don't want to store multiple audio clips in the local database as I want my app to be more light.

Thanks in advance.